# How to place toggle button in bottom of screen in navigation drawer?

Tags: android, navigation, toggle

Hi I am working with android navigation drawer.I had created a navigation drawer in my app which handle the action with home button at the top.Now How can I change to my custom button and how can I placed the button at the left bottom of the screen.Please help me I am new to android,Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score -1):

use the following two properties in Button in .xml file

```
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
```

First one will align your button to the bottom of your screen and second will set the alignment to left.

Comment: I didn;t mean placing of button..Home button is navigation drawer handler